# How to configure Typescript so it "knows about" my SystemJS paths?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, jspm

Currently I have to import my modules using relative paths:

```
import {UserService} from "../../../services/user-service";
```

However, I'd rather configure SystemJS so that resolution begins at the root of the app unless the module path starts with `./`, then I can do this (`services` is at the root):

```
import {UserService} from "services/user-service";
```

And if I want to import a file from the current location:

```
import {Something} from "./something";
```

I can configure the first part with SystemJS:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    transpiler: false,
    paths: {
        "*": "dist/*",
        "services": "dist/services/*",
        "models": "dist/models/*",
        "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
        "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
    },
    // ...
}
```

However...

1. I'm not sure how to make Typescript aware of my `SystemJS.paths` config, and
2. I don't know how to configure SystemJS to "load things from the root by default".

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to configure a package in SystemJs and to add path mappings for typescript.

You can do this by adding a index.ts file under the services directory like:

```
export { UserService } from './user-service';
export { OrderService } from './order-service';
...
```

Add the following to your SystemJs config(See: [SytemJS config-api](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/0.19.16/docs/config-api.md#packages)):

```
SystemJS.config({
  ...
  packages: {
    "services": {
      "main": "index.ts"
    }
  }
});
```

Add this to tsconfig.json (See: [Typescript module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "services": [ "services" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can now import a file like:

```
import { UserService } from 'services';
```

This will provide intellisense in Visual Studio and allow modules to load in the browser.